# Attribute class to parent from child

Tags: jquery

How can i attribute the class of a child to its parent ?

```
<div><div class="child"></div></div>
<div><div class="child_one"></div></div>
<div><div class="child_two"></div></div>
```

so the resulting html would look like this

```
<div class="child"><div class="child"></div></div>
<div class="child_one"><div class="child_one"></div></div>
<div class="child_two"><div class="child_two"></div></div>
```

tried these , but both give the div wraps the same classes

```
$('div').addClass( $('div > div').attr("class") );

$('div').each(function( index ) {
  $(this).addClass($('div > div').attr("class"));
});

$('div').each(function( index ) {
  $(this).closest('div').addClass(this).attr("class");
});
```

Comment: Please include [your attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe what specifically goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

ok figured it out

```
$('div').each(function( index ) {
  $(this).parent('div').addClass($(this).attr("class"));
});
```